# Convert Seq of Objects to List of Strings

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I am new to scala and I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   :     scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[UserDAOImpl.this.PermissionRow]]
[error]  required: List[String]
[error]           Some(db.run(unionPermissionQuery.result)),
```

I would like to convert it from `scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[UserDAOImpl.this.PermissionRow]]` to `List[String]` where the string is `PermissionRow.name`

`PermissionRow` case class:

```
/** Entity class storing rows of table Permission
* @param id Database column id SqlType(INT), AutoInc, PrimaryKey
* @param name Database column name SqlType(VARCHAR), Length(45,true)
* @param categorytype Database column categoryType SqlType(VARCHAR), Length(45,true)
* @param created Database column created SqlType(DATETIME)
* @param updated Database column updated SqlType(DATETIME) */
  case class PermissionRow(id: Int, name: String, categorytype: String, created: Option[java.sql.Timestamp], updated: Option[java.sql.Timestamp])
```

The derived list should contain only the name of each `PermissionRow`

Comment: Please attach some code here.

Comment: I thought it wasn't necessary :) but I attached my `PermissionRow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
val f: Future[Seq[UserDAOImpl.this.PermissionRow]] = ???
```

you can do

```
val f1: Future[List[String]] f.map(_.map(_.name).toList)
```

now you can put the list inside `Result`

```
val res = f1.map(Ok(_))
```

and return it

to return a `Future` you need to use `Action.async` instead of `Action`

**edit:**

If you need `Option[List[String]]` you need to modify what is inside `Future` `Some(someFuture)` won't work as you will get `Option[Future[List[String]]]`. To change what is inside `Future` you should use map. In your case you can replace `res` line I gave you above with

```
val res: Future[Result[Option[List[String]]]] = f1.map(Ok(Some(_)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just a quick fix. I want to save the list to a variable `Option[List[String]]`. I tried `Some(f1)` but that returns `Option[Future[List[String]]]`

Comment: I see you're getting help with that now at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089193/convert-futureliststring-to-liststring

Comment: I adressed your comment in my answer.