# Convert Future[List[String]] to List[String]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following code:

```
Some(db.run(unionPermissionQuery.result).map(_.map(_.name).toList))
```

and I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]
[error]  required: List[String]
[error]           Some(db.run(unionPermissionQuery.result).map(_.map(_.name).toList)),
[error]                                                       ^
[error] one error found
```

So I suppose I have to convert the `Future[List[String]]` to `List[String]`. I am new to scala sorry if that's too easy.

Full code:

```
  def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[models.admin.User]] = {
val userQuery = for {
  dbLoginInfo <- loginInfoQuery(loginInfo)
  dbUserLoginInfo <- Userlogininfo.filter(_.logininfoid === dbLoginInfo.id)
  dbUser <- User.filter(_.userid === dbUserLoginInfo.userid)
} yield dbUser

db.run(userQuery.result.headOption).map { dbUserOption =>
  dbUserOption.map { user =>
    val permissionQuery = for {
      dbUserPermission <- Userpermission.filter(_.userid === user.userid)
      dbPermission <- Permission.filter(_.id === dbUserPermission.permissionid)
    } yield dbPermission

    val rolePermissionQuery = for {
      dbUserRole <- Userrole.filter(_.userid === user.userid)
      dbRole <- Role.filter(_.id === dbUserRole.roleid)
      dbRolePermission <- Rolepermission.filter(_.roleid === dbRole.id)
      dbPermission <- Permission.filter(_.id === dbRolePermission.permissionid)
    } yield dbPermission

    val unionPermissionQuery = permissionQuery union rolePermissionQuery

    models.admin.User(
      UUID.fromString(user.userid),
      user.firstname,
      user.lastname,
      user.jobtitle,
      loginInfo,
      user.email,
      user.emailconfirmed,
      Some(db.run(unionPermissionQuery.result).map(_.map(_.name).toList)),
      user.enabled)
  }
}
```

I just want to get the user and then fill all permissions. Individual permissions and permissions inherited by the role assigned to the user.

Is it better to get the user and then perform another request to get the permissions based on the user id? I don't think so.

Comment: Although never having worked with `Future`s, I expect the only way to get a value out of a `Future` is to wait, which means calling `result` for the STD-lib `Future` class. That's the meaning of `Future`, no?

Comment: Please supply the context. In the *Play!* you are probably should always avoid `Await`ing, so I suppose, you should adapt surrounding code to work with `Future`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## General information on futures

You will find all information on *Futures* you need on
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html.

A possible approach is awaiting the result, but it is not good to use in a prod application.

```
val myFutureResult : Future[T] = Future {...}
val myResult : T = Await.result(myFutureResult, secondsToWait seconds)
```

Normally instead of awaiting the result and storing it in a variable you can `map` the future and compose it and only use Await at the last moment.

```
val myFutureResult : Future[T] = Future {...}
def myFunctionOnT(in: T) = ...

for {res <- myFutureResult } yield myFunctionOnT(res)
```

## Play and Futures

Play itself can handle `Future[T]`by default by using `Action.async {}` instead of `Action{}` here you can find more: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync

## This information applied to extended question

```
db.run(unionPermissionQuery.result).map(_.map(_.name).toList).map { permission =>

models.admin.User(
  UUID.fromString(user.userid),
  user.firstname,
  user.lastname,
  user.jobtitle,
  loginInfo,
  user.email,
  user.emailconfirmed,
  Some(permission),
  user.enabled)
  }
```

Comment: But I want to save the result in a variable not return it through an action

Comment: It looks more like comment, than actual answer

Comment: It is an answer. But OP is very likely asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering the question in the title.

The **only** way to implement the function `Future[A] => A` in a sensible way (and without access to a time-machine) is to await the completion of the future, as a value `Future[A]` indicates a value of type `A` will yield in the future.

Check your library for the correct method to wait. <strike>For the Scala std lib it is `.result`.</strike> As commented by Jean, the correct way for the Scala std lib is to use `Await.result()`.

Note that waiting is a *blocking* method call. If you want to avoid this (and there are some good reasons to do so), you should check out Andreas' answer.

Comment: As indicated in the scala documentation, the correct way to block and get a value out of a `scala.concurrent.Future` is to use `Await.result()`. See `This method should not be called directly; use Await.result instead.` in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@result(atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)(implicitpermit:scala.concurrent.CanAwait):T